# delete rows not correspondent in sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I find here  a solution to delete row in one table not corresponding to another table with a where id condition:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable1 WHERE id=1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable2 WHERE id=1)
```

But I have about 10000 rows that Id's in MyTable1 are not in MyTable2, and is very trying to find out what Id's from a MyTable1 are not corresponding in MyTable2

How can I delete all the rows of on MyTable1  that are not correspondent in MyTable2 without having the where id condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete all rows in MyTable1 that have id not present in MyTable2.

`DELETE FROM MyTable1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM MyTable2`)

Comment: I also find a way using NOT EXISTS. But thak you for the thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that by `NOT EXISTS`. But you sub-query should a `correlated sub-query`

```
DELETE FROM MyTable1 A
WHERE  id = 1
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   MyTable2 B
                       WHERE  A.id = B.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either join on id MyTable2 and check that id will be null or you could create a constraint to not allow the deletion of a row in table1 where the id exist in table2

Comment: I find a way using NOT EXISTS. But thank you for the thoughts,